# Android issue in using redlaser sdk

Tags: android, barcode

I am using redlaser api in my app. I am getting "Resource not found" exception in the anim folder. But I am not using any of the animation file in the acitivity where I am using the redlaser. Its showing the error in the first file of anim folder, If I delete that file, then its showing the error in the next file (which is first now).

I have attached the exception as screen shot here

[image]

You can see that the error is there in the api, showing the error in the following line

```
com.ebay.redlasersdk.scanner.BarcodeScanActivity.initBeepSound(BarcodeScanActivity.java:353)
```

Comment: Please post logs as text, image is too small to see the stack trace.

Comment: im posting the error as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the getBeepResource() method that you have implemented in your activity, fully qualify the name of the resource by adding the package name of your R.java file.  For example, in the RLSample project the getBeepResource() method is implemented in the RedLaserSDK.java file.  In that method replace the line returning the resource with this line:

return com.ebay.rlsample.R.raw.beep;

This will fix the issue.  Do the same in your app code as well (changing the package name to match your app).